# Will this static var work like C?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, swift2

I want to define a static variable on a class using Swift 2 that is a NSLock.

After researching I discovered that I have to use a struct, in something like this:

```
class Entity: NSManagedObject {

  struct Mechanism {
    static let lock = NSLock()
  }

  func myFunction -> NSArray {

    Mechanism.lock.lock()

    // do something

    Mechanism.lock.unlock()

  }

}
```

Will this work like C? I mean, the first time Mechanism is used a static lock constant will be created and subsequent calls will use the same constant?

I feel that this is not correct because the line

```
static let lock = NSLock()
```

is initializing a NSLock. So it will initialize a new one every time.

If this was not swift I would do like this:

```
static NSLock *lock;

if (!lock) {
  lock = ... initialize 
}
```

How do I do the equivalent in Swift 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that "after researching, I discovered that I have to use a struct [to get a static]." You then go on to ask whether it really is a static a how it changes in Swift 2.0.

So, a couple of observations:

1. Yes, this static within a struct pattern will achieve the desired behavior, that only one `NSLock` will be instantiated.
2. The significant change in the language was in Swift 1.2 (not 2.0), which now allows static variables, eliminating the need for the `struct` altogether:

   ```
   class Entity: NSManagedObject {

       static let lock = NSLock()

       func myFunction() -> NSArray {
           Entity.lock.lock()
           // do something
           Entity.lock.unlock()
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: If I do that, when I tray to use lock.lock() inside the function it gives me an error **Entity does not have a member named lock**

Comment: @SpaceDog My bad. You have to reference `Entity.lock`, not just `lock`.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, nobody uses NSLock on MacOS X or iOS. In Objective C, you use @synchronized. In Swift, you use a global function like this:

```
func Synchronized (obj: AnyObject, _ block: dispatch_block_t)
{
    objc_sync_enter (obj)
    block ()
    objc_sync_exit (obj)
}
```

First, this uses a recursive lock. That alone will safe you gazillions of headaches. Second, it works much more fine grained, with a lock for one specific object. To use:

```
func myFunction() -> NSArray {
    Synchronized(someObject) {
        // Stuff to do. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. If I use your scheme and put the do/catch block of my executeFetchRequest inside, it will give me an error **invalid conversion from throwing function of type ()throws -> Void to non-throwing function...**

Comment: can you please rewrite the part you use Synchronized with my executeFetchRequest block?

Comment: He's probably trying to return the `NSArray` reference from within the `Synchronized` closure, which won't work. You have to have some local variable declared before the closure, have the closure update that variable, and then have the function return that variable from outside of the closure.

Comment: BTW, gnasher, I'm not sure I share your enthusiasm for @synchronized. It was incredibly convenient for simple stuff in Objective-C, but it's slower. And to say "nobody uses NSLock" is overstating the case (e.g. well established frameworks like AFNetworking uses it). Besides, Apple advises that we don't use locks at all anymore and use queues instead.